# Problemas com redimensionamento de site

Tags: css, html5, css3, layout-responsivo, html5-video

Boa tarde!

Gostaria da ajuda de vocês com um projeto de site pessoal meu, estou enfrentando um ou dois problemas com ele, mas vamos pelo inicio.

- Primeiro: Quando eu redimensiono o site para valores menores 375px, ocorre um quebra de layout, na qual a tag video expande dando uma impressão de ser maior em width do que os outras tag de html.

Vai imagem em anexo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Link do site: https://moisesdesenvolvedorweb.000webhostapp.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu consegui resolver aqui tirando os widths do inputs, vc colocou nele um valor em PX que esta limitando a responsividade do container.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nesse `button` tira esse valor fixo de `margin`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E nessa `div` coloca `width` 100% (`class="formulario"`)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito obrigado Hugo, já entendi o que devo fazer. Eu estava tentando mexer na tag video, ja que pra mim o problema era com ela, não tinha pensando no tamanho fixo dos elementos.

Comment: @MoisesFausto sem problemas, que bom que resolveu!